# What is the mess Lydia is in?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was in Riften when one of the random Thief events happened. All the locals were attacking the thief and Lydia joined in. I guess she must have hit one of the guards at some point because they started attacking her. I couldn't do anything about it, so I wandered off and went to sleep at the inn. When I went back outside the next day she is standing in the square and says, "Well this is a nice mess you've gotten me into" and I have the option to say "Let's go. Let me worry about the guards."

What happened? Is she in trouble with the guards? If I tell her I will deal with the guards will I get attacked?

Comment: Good one! I found [this related issue](http://www.thenexusforums.com/index.php?/topic/135092-my-companion-turned-into-an-outlaw/) talking about Oblivion, but sounds very relevant in your case as well. (Bottom line - try to reset her bounty with console commands)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't think its possible to set the bounty of a follower in Skyrim.  The whole concept of bounty seems to be tied to the player.

Comment: @yx. I don't think it's that far fetched.. if the gaming mechanism allowed a follower to attack guards maybe it also have "hidden bounty" as a result. But of course I might be wrong, didn't find any official data about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After I chose the option to go, the guards immediately started attacking me. I sheathed my weapons to surrender and was able to use the Thane option to avoid paying a bounty. It seems that as soon as you choose to leave, the bounty for your follower gets transferred to you and the guards act accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a save you can go to when you first entered the city. Just make sure she doesn't hit another guard. You know what is going to happen so make her wait at the gate then go kill the thief.

If you don't want to do that then you might have to pay a lot of money for her bounty. It will be big because she did kill all the guards that was attacking her.

Comment: How do you pay the bounty on followers? Do you just talk to a guard and then fork over whatever they ask for?

Comment: @Sterno Sounds like an excellent question to post on the site.

Comment: @Iszi I'd rather see this answer updated. As it is, I've never seen this sort of thing happen to a follower in game and thus I'm not sure it's possible as doger says. I'm curious if he has first-hand experience with it, or is guessing.